# How do you build a circuit to make an equal superposition of $n$ outcomes?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction, entanglement

Suppose we start with $|00...0\rangle$.
We want to build an equal superposition over $|0\rangle + ... + |n-1\rangle$.

When $n=2^m$ for some $m$, I know I can do this using $H^{\otimes m}$.

What is the general circuit for this (i.e. in case $n$ is not power of 2)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How to prepare a uniform superposition over a range.

**Simple: Repeat until success**

The simplest approach is to prepare an $n$-qubit quantum integer register $k$, where $n=\lceil \lg_2 N \rceil$, in the state $|+\rangle^{\otimes n}$. That can be done very cheaply using reset gates and Hadamard gates. Then use a comparison operation to measure whether $k<N$ or not. If not, then retry. The main downside of this repeat-until-success approach is that it isn't reversible, and sometimes these sorts of preparation tasks occur inside subroutines  where reversibility is needed due to controlling and uncomputing the preparation.

> [Example repeat-until-success circuit in Quirk, cycling over N=1 to N=127](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B%22Counting7%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%7C1%E2%9F%A9%E2%9F%A81%7C%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C1%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22Swap%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Swap%22%2C%22%E2%80%A2%22%5D%2C%5B%22inputA7%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5E%3DA7%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance7%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Chance7%22%5D%2C%5B%22Uncounting7%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22Amps7%22%5D%5D%7D) (technically should only go from 65 to 127 for a 7 qubit system like this):
>
> [image]

**Flexible: Amplitude Amplification**

There is a deterministic reversible circuit with the same cost as the repeat-until-success strategy. You can [use a single step of amplitude amplification](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.03662), with a less-than-N comparison as the oracle, to get to a uniform superposition over the range [0, N). This has a gate count of $O(\lg N+\lg\frac{1}{\epsilon})$, where the $\epsilon$ comes from how closely you approximate the rotation angle within the amplification.

- Remove any factors of two in $N$ by adding a qubit in the $|+\rangle$ state. $N$ is now odd. Skip the remaining steps if $N=1$.
- Let $\theta = \arccos(1 - 2^{\lfloor \lg_2 N \rfloor} / N)$.
- Perform one step of amplification. Use a diffusion angle of $\theta$. Use $f(k) = k < N$ as the oracle.
- The system is now in the desired state.

> [Example amplification circuit in Quirk, for N=100](https://algassert.com/quirk#circuit=%7B%22cols%22%3A%5B%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22setB%22%2C%22arg%22%3A25%7D%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%2C%22H%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22inputA5%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5EA%3CB%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22Rzft%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22acos(1-16%2F25)%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22inputA5%22%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%22%5EA%3CB%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22Rzft%22%2C%22arg%22%3A%22acos(1-16%2F25)%22%7D%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22%E2%8A%95%22%2C%22X%22%5D%2C%5B%22Chance7%22%5D%2C%5B%22Amps7%22%5D%5D%7D)
>
> [image]